# Gulp minify multiple js files to one

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am new to Gulp and wondering how can I minify (concatinate) my collection to single file instead of every file separately.

#### Example

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('minify', function () {
   gulp.src([
        'content/plugins/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.js',
        'content/plugins/jquery/jquery-ui.js',
        'content/js/client.js'])
      .pipe(uglify())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('content/js/client.min.js')) // It will create folder client.min.js
});

gulp.task('default', ['minify']);
```

As you can see I'm trying to minify 3 javascript files and then output them into one `client.min.js`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

This plugin will help [gulp-concat](https://github.com/wearefractal/gulp-concat).

Usage:

```
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  gulp.src(['./lib/file3.js', './lib/file1.js', './lib/file2.js'])
    .pipe(concat('all.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'))
});
```

Comment: so uglify does js minification by default?

Comment: Does this also work for concatenating and minifying css and html files?

Comment: @IamC.S.S. Yes, the same approach should work, but instead of uglify you need eg. `gulp-minify-css`.

Comment: Better to uglify first (all files will be minified separately, one by one), then concat. This lets to avoid some of problems in resulting script.
Variant 2 - concat with some glue
Variant 3 - use Google closure compiler to do both task.

Comment: If I would have a `require` from file1.js to file3.js it would not work, right?  (in file1.js `require("./file3")`)

Comment: If I grouped files, How do I access the function of each files for UnitTesting using Mocha.

Answer (score 12):

Instead of going through a lots of tricky things, I recommend you getting `laravel-elixir`. It is compiling sass, less, babel, coffescript and even adding something that you want with not just JavaScript but also with css. All the code that you will need will be:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.scripts(['app.js', 'controllers.js', 'sweetalert.js'], 'public/js/all.js');
    mix.styles(['normalize.css', 'app.css', 'sweetalert.css'], 'public/css/all.css')
});
```

Comment: Overkill, specially for people new to gulp.

Comment: Why overkill? It's a one time job on your local pc. You dont have to worry about client performance.

Comment: _Elexir_ lives in _Laravel_'s media only! It needs exact infrastructure for most tasks.

Comment: and what about the performance of the minifing. compare with gulp

Answer (score 3):

Lets try [gulp-concat-util](https://github.com/mgcrea/gulp-concat-util) for joining **scripts**. It's similar to concat, but have some helpers to glue files. There is special helper to concatinate scripts.

```
var concat = require('gulp-concat-util');

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  gulp.src(['./lib/file3.js', './lib/file1.js', './lib/file2.js'])
    .pipe(concat.scripts('all.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'))
});
```