# Laravel minify css and js files

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, gulp

I receive custom js and css script as a string through html form. This strings are then saved in files on filesystem. The question is how to minify those files every time they are generated/updated. I am using gulp and laravel elixir. 
My first idea was to call exec("gulp something") but not sure how to configure gulp.

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/elixir

Comment: You probably didn't understand the question. I want to minify custom js or css file with gulp through laravel app.

Comment: Refer the below answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26719884/gulp-minify-multiple-js-files-to-one and added few gulp module as well

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Requirments:

- [gulp-newer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-newer)
- [minifyCss](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-minify-css)
- [gulp-uglify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify)

**First step:**(*install plugins*)

**minifyCss** and **gulp-uglify** are used by laravel-elixir. You have to install **gulp-newer** by `npm install gulp-newer --save-dev`.

**Second step:**(*define task*)

You need to define different tasks for css and js.

**CSS task**

```
gulp.task('cssTask', function() {
            return gulp.src(cssSrc)
                .pipe(newer(cssDest))//compares the css source and css destination(css files)
                .pipe(minifyCss())//minify css
                .pipe(gulp.dest(cssDest));//save minified css in destination directory 
        });
```

**Js task**

```
gulp.task('jsTask', function() {
            return gulp.src(jsSrc)
                .pipe(newer(jsDest))//compares the js source and js destination(js files)
                .pipe(uglify())//minify js
                .pipe(gulp.dest(jsDest));//save minified js in destination directory 
        });
```

**Third step:**(*define custom watch*)

You should have a watch task which watches your source directories(`cssSrc` and `jsSrc`) and calls its related task.

```
gulp.task('custom', function() {//Watch task
            gulp.watch(cssSrc, ['cssTask']);//watch your css source and call css task
            gulp.watch(jsSrc, ['jsTask']);//watch your js source and call js task
        });
```

**Fourth step:**(*run custom watch*)

Finally, you must run the custom task by `gulp custom`.

**Conclusion:**

Every time, when file is added to the source directory. Gulp will minify the file and store it in destination directory. This is tested locally and it works perfectly.

**Completed Gulp file**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
var newer = require('gulp-newer');
var minifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

cssSrc = 'cssSrc/*.css';//Your css source directory
cssDest = 'cssDest';//Your css destination directory

jsSrc = 'jsSrc/*.js';//Your js source directory
jsDest = 'jsDest';//Your js destination directory


gulp.task('cssTask', function() {
    return gulp.src(cssSrc)
        .pipe(newer(cssDest))//compares the css source and css destination(css files)
        .pipe(minifyCss())//minify css
        .pipe(gulp.dest(cssDest));//save minified css in destination directory 
});

gulp.task('jsTask', function() {
    return gulp.src(jsSrc)
        .pipe(newer(jsDest))//compares the js source and js destination(js files)
        .pipe(uglify())//minify js
        .pipe(gulp.dest(jsDest));//save minified js in destination directory 
});

gulp.task('custom', function() {//Watch task
    gulp.watch(cssSrc, ['cssTask']);//watch your css source and call css task
    gulp.watch(jsSrc, ['jsTask']);//watch your js source and call js task
});
```

**Edited after comment:**

> I would like something like this: gulp custom srcFile destFile.

For that situation, you need to install new plugin which is called [yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs).

**Installation:**

You can install yargs by `npm install yargs --save-dev` and then you have to pass source directory and destination directory when custom task is called.

```
gulp custom  --cssSrc=cssSource --cssDest=cssDestination --jsSrc=jsSource --jsDest=jsDestination
```

**For example:**

```
gulp custom  --cssSrc=cssSrc/*.css --cssDest=cssDest --jsSrc=jsSrc/*.js --jsDest=jsDest
```

The completed Gulp file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
var newer = require('gulp-newer');
var minifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var argv = require('yargs').argv;

cssSrc = argv.cssSrc;
cssDest = argv.cssDest;

jsSrc = argv.jsSrc;
jsDest = argv.jsDest;



gulp.task('cssTask', function() {
    return gulp.src(cssSrc)
        .pipe(newer(cssDest))
        .pipe(minifyCss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(cssDest));
});

gulp.task('jsTask', function() {
    return gulp.src(jsSrc)
        .pipe(newer(jsDest))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(jsDest));
});

gulp.task('custom', function() {
    gulp.watch(cssSrc, ['cssTask']);
    gulp.watch(jsSrc, ['jsTask']);
});
```

**Note: Every time, the source directory or destination directory is changed, gulp task must be called again.**

Comment: Looks nice but it would be really cool if I could pass Src and Dest paths as argument. Because each Src and Dest file is on different location. So for example i would like something like this: gulp custom srcFile destFile

Comment: @izupet I think it can be done. I'll check it and update my answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below gulp modules.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-minify-css - Minify all your css files.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat-css - Merge all your css in to one file.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify - Minigy all your JS files.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass - SASS

Refer this answer:
[Gulp minify multiple js files to one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26719884/gulp-minify-multiple-js-files-to-one)

Below is sample Gulp File Snippet.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
  sass = require('gulp-sass'),
  autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
  jshint = require('gulp-jshint'),
  uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
  imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
  rename = require('gulp-rename'),
  clean = require('gulp-clean'),
  concat = require('gulp-concat'),
  notify = require('gulp-notify'),
  cache = require('gulp-cache'),
  livereload = require('gulp-livereload'),
  lr = require('tiny-lr'),
  server = lr();

// Clean
gulp.task('clean', function() {
  return gulp.src(['css', 'js', 'img'], {
      read: false
    })
    .pipe(clean());
});


gulp.task('styles', function() {
  return gulp.src('sass/styles.scss')
    .pipe(sass({
      style: 'expanded'
    }))
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
    .pipe(notify({
      message: 'Styles task complete'
    }));
});

// Concatenate & Minify JS
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src('js/*.js')
    .pipe(concat('all.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
    .pipe(rename('all.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});


// Watch
gulp.task('watch', function() {

  // Watch .scss files
  gulp.watch('sass/**/*.scss', ['styles']);

  // Watch .js files
  gulp.watch('js/**/*.js', ['scripts']);

  // Watch image files
  gulp.watch('img/**/*', ['images']);

  // Create LiveReload server
  var server = livereload();

  // Watch any files in dist/, reload on change
  gulp.watch(['sass/**', 'js/**', 'img/**', '*.html']).on('change', function(file) {
    server.changed(file.path);
  });

});


gulp.task('default', ['styles', 'scripts', 'watch']);
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10591438)

Comment: i agree with your point. let me update gul config snippet. but I'm curius, question is in general. i don't see its required to have snippet. anyways

Comment: If the links change, then the answer may be useless.  If the question is in general, then perhaps a "cut and paste" of the essentials from the link would be in line.

Answer (score 0):

At first place, you need to store the content in a new file. A good place for this is `resources/assets/js`:

```
$jsContent = $request->get('js_custom_content');
file_put_contents(base_path('resources/assets/js/custom.js'), $jsContent);
```

Ok, once created the javascript file, you need to tell to elixir to minify the custom script:

```
// it will look for resources/assets/js/custom.js
// and it will compress the output to public/assets/js/custom.min.js
mix.scripts(['custom.js'], 'public/assets/js/custom.min.js');
```

Optionally, you can version it. That means that everytime the script's content change, gulp will generate a new version in order to avoid browser's cache issues:

```
mix.version(['public/assets/js/custom.min.js']);
```

Finally, load the script in your view:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url('assets/js/custom.min.js')) }}"></script>
```

Or with version:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url(elixir('assets/js/custom.min.js')) }}"></script>
```

Comment: Maybe my question was not clear enough but this is not what i am looking for. I recevice strings through form and i save this content to files. This files are stored in different locations on filesytem (not in resource/assets/js) because this files has no relation with app which produces them. Those generated files are then used for other things. I want to know how to minify those spreaded files on demand. The command to minify will be triggered by php script.

Comment: Oh! I got it. The people get confused because of laravel's tag. You need to delegate the work to a nodej's module for this specific purpose outside of lavaral's scope

Answer (score 0):

In laravel i use gulp to minify and copy assets folder to public like this

package.json :

```
{
   "private": true,
   "type": "module",
   "scripts": {
       "copyAsset": "gulp copyFileTask",
       "minifyAsset": "gulp cssMinifyTask jsMinifyTask"
   },
   "devDependencies": {
       "gulp": "^4.0.2",
       "gulp-clean-css": "^4.3.0",
       "gulp-minify": "^3.1.0",
       "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.2"
   }
}
```

gulpfile.js :

```
const gulp  = require('gulp');
const cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('copyFileTask', function() {
    return gulp.src('./resources/assets/**/*.*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/assets'))
});

gulp.task('cssMinifyTask', function() {
    return gulp.src('./resources/assets/**/*.css')
        .pipe(cleanCSS({compatibility: 'ie8'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/assets'))
});

gulp.task('jsMinifyTask', function() {
    return gulp.src('./resources/assets/**/*.js')
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/assets'))
});
```

now you can run

```
npm i
npm run copyAsset
npm run minifyAsset
```

All the resource/assets/ files copy and minify and uglify to public/assets/

**Notice:** you should install node version 8.*