# loading js from single file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 4 js files I want to load from a single file.

in my footer I have the following link

```
<script src="content/vendor/js/utils.js"></script>
```

utils.js is the main file.

the files I want to load are in content/vendor/js/gsap

I have the following code in my utilities file but it does not seem to load the files because the effects stop working.

```
// JavaScript Document
=== all.js ===
(function() {
    'use strict';
    var a = [
       'TweenMax.min',
       'ScrollMagic',
       'animation.gsap',
       'jquery.placeholder',
       ...
    ];
    var i;
    var s = [];
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i += 1) {
        s = s.concat(['<script src="/gsap/', a[i], '.js"></script>']);
    }
    document.write(s.join(''));
}());
```

Comment: `"it does not seem to load the files"` - Then what *does* it do?  When you debug this, how specifically is it failing?

Comment: I have pin effects and text effects once I comment out the full links in the main page and use the single page with them included the animations stop working.

Comment: That's unfortunate, but "stuff doesn't work" isn't really an answerable question.  Use your browser's debugging tools to determine what ***is*** happening when you run this code.  What output do you expect from the code in the question, and what output is it actually giving you?

Comment: well if I knew why it wasn't working I don't think I would be asking

Comment: And we can help you determine what the problem is, if you can provide information about that problem.  You could start by at least *looking* at the results of your code.  Stack Overflow can be very helpful, but this community isn't a replacement for any effort at all on your part.

Comment: You have to escape the slash in the closing script tag or split up the string more, if you want to document.write. The better idea though, is to never use document.write and just create new script ndoes and append them. This will immediately download and execute the scripts once the script tag gets inserted and gets around the issues with document.write + script tags, since document.write gets really confused about the closing </script> tag.

Comment: Why don't you create a [Gulp script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26719941/1762224) to do this for you???

Comment: He's asking for a 'module loader', not a 'build/concatenation' tool.

Comment: @Shilly Yeah, but which one is better for performance?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you might want to do this in a single JavaScript file, but it seems to add unnecessary overhead.

> I have 4 js files I want to load from a single file

You can place all of those into a single html file and use an link tag:

```
<link rel="import" href="js-loader.html">
```

In js-loader.html:

```
<script src="/gsap/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="/gsap/ScrollMagic.js"></script>
<script src="/gsap/animation.gsap.js"></script>
<script src="/gsap/jquery.placeholder"></script>
```

This is how it is done at the company I work at, plus it seems a bit more readable (though that is our opinion).

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned with performance, you may want to create a single JavaScript file using a utility like Gulp. This will also handle the minification for you.

Here's an easy [setup guide](https://markgoodyear.com/2014/01/getting-started-with-gulp/).

## Setup

- Download [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)
- Install [gulp](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md)

### gulpfile.js

```js
var gulp   = require('gulp'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  gulp.src([
       'TweenMax.min',
       'ScrollMagic',
       'animation.gsap',
       'jquery.placeholder'
      ].map(name => '/gsap/' + name + '.js'))
    .pipe(concat('all.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'))
});
```

Then run this command.

```
gulp scripts
```

Finally, include this in your HTML.

```
<script src="dist/all.js"></script>
```

---

If you really want to load them dynamically, here is a [script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1867135/1762224) that was written by user [nemisj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/219703/nemisj).

```js
function loadScripts(array, callback) {
  const loader = (src, handler) => {
    let script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = src;
    script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = () => {
      script.onreadystatechange = script.onload = null;
      handler();
    }
    let head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    (head || document.body).appendChild(script);
  };
  (function run() {
    array.length != 0 ? loader(array.shift(), run) : (callback && callback())
  })();
}

loadScripts([
  'TweenMax.min',
  'ScrollMagic',
  'animation.gsap',
  'jquery.placeholder'
].map(name => '/gsap/' + name + '.js'), function() {
  alert('Finished loading scripts...');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The function below does the trick for me. It links the files `second.js` and `third.js` to the document. `index.js` is:

```
// index.js
(function () {
    var paths = ['second', 'third'];
    for (path in paths) {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script['src'] = paths[path] + '.js';

        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }
}());
```

And the `index.html` is:

```
// index.html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```