# How to build a production release with gulp ?

Tags: javascript, gulp

I want to build using gulp.

I have made some changes in index.html file in dev folder and css files in and a tmp folder for css.

When I run gulp build:dist it is deleting all my dev files and tmp files and producing some files in new folder dist.

The problem is that it is not compressing the exact same files which I made in the dev folder(after change). It is taking the original files and compressing them.

Here is the content of my gulpfile.js

```js
'use strict';

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Plugins                                                          //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var gulp = require('gulp');
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('sync-request');
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var reload = browserSync.reload;
var notify = require('gulp-notify');
var del = require('del');
var useref = require('gulp-useref');
var rev = require('gulp-rev');
var revReplace = require('gulp-rev-replace');
var revDel = require('gulp-rev-delete-original');
var size = require('gulp-size');
var critical = require('critical');
var ico = require('gulp-to-ico');
var run = require('gulp-run-command').default;
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var preprocess = require('gulp-preprocess');
var handlebars = require('gulp-compile-handlebars');


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Setup                                                            //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var config = require('./build/build.config.js');
var templateData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./variables.js'));


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Sketch                                                           //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//// Export assets from sketch file
gulp.task('sketch', run('sketchtool export slices --compact=YES --save-for-web=YES sketch/code-test.sketch --output=client/img'))


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Handlebars                                                       //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var hbOptions = {
  ignorePartials: true,
  batch : [config.base + config.partials],
  helpers : {}
};
var hbOptionsDist = {
  ignorePartials: true,
  batch : [config.dist + config.partials],
  helpers : {}
};

//// Inject Handlebar varibles for development
gulp.task('inject:dev', function(cb) {
  return gulp.src(config.html)
    .pipe(handlebars(templateData, hbOptions))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dev));
});

//// Inject Handlebar varibles for production
gulp.task('inject:dist', function(cb) {
  return gulp.src(config.dist + '/**/*.html')
    .pipe(handlebars(templateData, hbOptionsDist))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist));
});


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Images                                                           //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//// optimize images and put them in the dist folder
gulp.task('images', function() {
  return gulp.src(config.images)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist + '/img'))
    .pipe(size({
      title: 'img'
    }));
});

//// Create the favicon from the png
gulp.task('favicon', ['copy:fav'], function() {
  return gulp.src(config.dist + '/favicon.png')
    .pipe(ico('favicon.ico'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist));
});


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// SASS to CSS                                                      //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//// Sass compilation, sourcemaps, autoprefixing and minification
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src(config.mainScss)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass())
    .on('error', sass.logError)
    .on("error", notify.onError({
        title: 'SASS ERROR',
    message: '<%= error.message %>',
    sound: true
    }))
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
        browsers: ['last 3 versions'],
        cascade: false
    }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.tmp))
    .pipe(size({
      title: 'sass'
    }));
});
gulp.task('sass:dist', function() {
  return gulp.src(config.mainScss)
    .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}))
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
        browsers: ['last 3 versions'],
        cascade: false
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.tmp))
    .pipe(size({
      title: 'sass'
    }));
});


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Critical CSS                                                     //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//// Grabs the critical CSS for a page load and inserts it above the page
gulp.task('critical', function () {
    return critical.generate({
        inline: true,
        base: './build/dist/',
        src: 'index.html',
        dest: 'index.html',
        width: 1300,
        height: 1000,
        minify: true
    });
});

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Run the REV                                                      //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

gulp.task('revision', function(){
  return gulp.src([config.dist + '/assets/**/*'])
    .pipe(rev())
    .pipe(revDel())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist + '/assets/'))
    .pipe(rev.manifest())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist + '/assets/'));
});

gulp.task('revisionReplace', function(){
  var manifest = gulp.src(config.dist + "/assets/rev-manifest.json");

  return gulp.src(config.dist + '/**/*.html')
  .pipe(revReplace({manifest: manifest}))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist));
});

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// HTML Build                                                       //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//// Concat CSS & JS files into single files, adds unique cache busting strings
//// Allows dev/prod if statements to show and hide content based on environment
gulp.task('html:dev', function() {
  return gulp.src(config.devhtml)
  .pipe(preprocess({context: { NODE_ENV: 'dev'}}))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dev))
});
gulp.task('html', function() {
  var manifest = gulp.src("build/dist/assets/rev-manifest.json");

  return gulp.src(config.html)
  .pipe(useref({
    searchPath: '{build,client}'
  }))
  .pipe(preprocess({context: { NODE_ENV: 'prod'}}))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist))
  .pipe(size({
    title: 'html'
  }));
});


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Copy                                                             //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//// Copy assets in dev folder
gulp.task('copy:dev', function() {
  return gulp.src([
    config.base + '/**/*',
    '!' + config.base + '/src'
  ])
  .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dev))
  .pipe(size({
    title: 'copy'
  }));
});

// Copy dev assets
gulp.task('copy:dev:assets', function() {
  return gulp.src([
    config.base + '/**/*',
    '!' + config.base + '/src',
    '!' + config.base + '/**/*.html'
  ])
  .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dev))
  .pipe(size({
    title: 'copy'
  }));
});

//// Copy assets in dist folder
gulp.task('copy', function() {
  return gulp.src([
    config.base + '/*',
    '!' + config.base + '/*.html',
    '!' + config.base + '/src'
  ])
  .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist))
  .pipe(size({
    title: 'copy'
  }));
});

//// Copy assets in dist folder
gulp.task('copy:assets', function() {
  return gulp.src(config.assets, {
    dot: true
  })
  .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist))
  .pipe(size({
    title: 'copy:assets'
  }));
});

//// Copy over the social and site config assets and place them in the root of the dist
gulp.task('copy:fav', function() {
  return gulp.src([
    config.base + '/img/fav/*',
    config.base + '/site-config/*'
  ])
  .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist))
  .pipe(size({
    title: 'copy:fav'
  }));
});


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Clean                                                            //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//// Clean temporary directories
gulp.task('clean', del.bind(null, [config.dev, config.tmp]));

//// Clean build transfered folders
gulp.task('clean:dist', del.bind(null, [
  'build/dist/scss',
  'build/dist/js',
  'build/dist/vendor',
  'build/dev',
  'build/tmp',
  'build/dist/img/fav',
  'build/dist/site-config'
]));

//// Remove partials from live
gulp.task('clean:partials', del.bind(null, [
  'build/dist/partials'
]));

//// Remove manifest from live
gulp.task('clean:manifest', del.bind(null, [
  'build/dist/assets/rev-manifest.json'
]));


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Builds                                                           //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//// Build files for creating a dist release for production
gulp.task('build:dist', ['clean'], function(cb) {
  runSequence(['build', 'copy', 'copy:assets', 'images'], ['html'], ['revision'], ['revisionReplace'], 'favicon', 'clean:dist', 'inject:dist', 'critical', 'clean:partials', 'clean:manifest', cb);
});

//// Build files for local development
gulp.task('build', ['clean'], function(cb) {
  runSequence(['sass:dist', 'copy:dev'], cb);
});


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Local server                                                     //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//// Run the development server after having built generated files, and watch for changes
gulp.task('serve', function() {
  runSequence('build', 'inject:dev', 'html:dev', function() {
    browserSync({
      notify: false,
      server: ['build', config.dev]
    });
  });
  gulp.watch(config.html, ['inject:dev'], ['html:dev', reload]);
  gulp.watch(config.scss, ['sass', reload]);
  gulp.watch([config.base + '/**/*', '!' + config.html, '!' + config.scss], ['copy:dev:assets', reload]);
});

//// Run the prod site packed in the dist folder
gulp.task('serve:dist', ['build:dist'], function() {
  browserSync({
    notify: false,
    server: [config.dist]
  });
});


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Tasks                                                            //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//// Default task
gulp.task('default', ['serve']);
```

Comment: because you are calling clean `gulp.task('build:dist', ['clean']` task, and its removing the files.

Comment: It may clean the files but its not performing optimization on the files which I changed. It is taking the original version of the file.

Comment: You want to minify the files?

Comment: yes optimize them

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26719941/3551786)